# CodeMirror copy preserving style

Tags: javascript, copy, codemirror

How to copy `javascript` code from CodeMirror preserving style.
If I copy and paste code from CodeMirror editor my coloring and style is dropped. Content is pasted as `text/plain`. Is there a way to save text formatting and style from editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Content is pasted as `text/plain`

It seems like this the normal behavior. However to copy from CodeMirror "preserving the style", you could use the [runmode](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_runmode) addon according to [this answer](https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/how-to-copy-text-with-markup-from-codemirror-editor-to-other-application/539/3).

A demo could be found here: http://codemirror.net/demo/runmode.html